# Dynamics Ax 2012 Dialog - Questioning Training material

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

In the training material I am going over it is setting 3 DialogFields as such(I also am showing the table declaration:

```
CustTable custTable;

dlgCust = dlg.addField(extendedTypeStr(CustVendAc),"Customer account");
dlgGrp  = dlg.addField(extendedTypeStr(CustGroupId));
dlgCur  = dlg.addField(extendedTypeStr(CurrencyCode));
```

Then it tries to save the values from the dialog box into the custTable

```
custTable.AccountNum = dlgCust.value();
custTable.CustGroup = dlgGrp.value();
custTable.Currency = dlgCur.value();
```

Why is it setting the DialogFields to one extended type just to move it to another?  CustVendAc, CustGroupId, and CurrencyCode all do not exist in CustTable.  What is the point of doing this?

A side question that is:

The lab I'm working on for this asks me:

> Create a new class that will prompt the user for a new customer
>   account number, the name and all fields that are mandatory for the
>   customer records. Use existing methods to validate the record before
>   inserting the record into the database. In the case that not all data
>   was entered, throw an error exception that has the error message:
>   "Please enter all required fields." The code to create the record must
>   be inside a try/catch statement. This must include a catch for the
>   error exception type and display the message: "An error occurred.
>   Please try again.".

It says to get the account number, the name, and all the fields that are mandatory for the customer record.  How am I suppose to determine this on my own?  I looked at the table and at the new Customer form and it asks for more information than what their solution gives... how do you determine what fields to ask for then?

Comment: This is a very well asked and well written question. Sadly in the AX SO community questions rarely receive upvotes. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CustTable.AccountNum` field in `CustTable` is of `CustAccount` type, which extends `CustVendAc` EDT. So basically, they both are of the same type.

`CustTable.CustGroup` is of `CustGroupId` type, so it is ok.

`CustTable.Currency` is of `CustCurrencyCode` type, which extends `CurrencyCode`.

> Use existing methods to validate the record before inserting the
>   record into the database.

Use `custTable.validateWrite` method to validate if the record can be created. It will return `false` if some mandatory records are missing and will show infolog with error message as well.

> It says to get the account number, the name, and all the fields that are mandatory for the customer record. How am I suppose to determine this on my own?

Each field in a table has `Mandatory` property.

The code woulld look like this:

```
try
{
    custTable.initValue();

    custTable.AccountNum = dlgCust.value();
    custTable.CustGroup = dlgGrp.value();
    custTable.Currency = dlgCur.value();

    //Other mendatory fields like customer name

    if (custTable.validateWrite())
    {
       ttsBegin;
       custTable.insert();
       ttsCommit;
    }
    else
    {
       throw error("Please enter all required fields");
    }
}
catch
{
    error("An error occurred. Please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dlgCust` is not an ExtendedDataType, it's a class object.  `DialogField`.

`CustTable.AccountNum` is a `Table.Field` you store the value in from the object.

Comment: CustVendAc is an extended num.. Where Why and how is this one chosen?  I'm assuming it's putting the user input into that field and putting it into digCust then it's assigned to AccountNum another extended data type in the table CustTable.

Comment: Ah I see your question. The EDT on the right side is used so the `DialogField` control knows how/what to present on the form by using AOT reflection. Instead of passing a string control, field length, help text, label, etc, you just pass an EDT and it figures out the details so you don't need to provide much.  If you use a Base Enum, it might give you a drop-down list. Or if you use `FileNameOpen`, it will have an option to open a common dialog control. Look in `\Classes\DialogField\init` to see where it's doing some reflection and `\Classes\Dialog\addField` to see the initial call. Arbitrary